# Javascript library for QR image decoder

Tags: javascript

I browse through few sites but did not find a code snippet to decode a QR code image in javascript. I gone through qrCode.js but all it has is QR code generator . I am looking for a qr code decoder which can decode a base64 QR image and get me the details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript QR Code Reader - can it be done? Or, Remote Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566972/javascript-qr-code-reader-can-it-be-done-or-remote-service)

Comment: @siva-a Have you found a solution that works with base64 image data? I have a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898063/decode-qr-code-from-data-uri).

Answer (score 7):

There is a JavaScript port of a Java library for reading qr codes: [Web QR](http://www.webqr.com/index.html)
The code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode)

From the readme:

> Usage:
>
> Include the scripts in the following order:
>
> ```html
> <script type="text/javascript" src="grid.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="version.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="detector.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="formatinf.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="errorlevel.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="bitmat.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="datablock.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="bmparser.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="datamask.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="rsdecoder.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="gf256poly.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="gf256.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="decoder.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="findpat.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="alignpat.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="databr.js"></script>
> ```
>
> To get the decoded information set:
>
> ```js
> qrcode.callback = function(decodedData) {
>     //...
> }
> ```
>
> Decode image with:
>
> ```js
> qrcode.decode(url or DataURL)
> ```
>
> Decode from canvas with "qr-canvas" ID:
>
> ```js
> qrcode.decode()
> ```

An [example](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/blob/master/src/test.html) can be also found in the repo.

Comment: Someone created a node package out of LazarSoft's code:
https://github.com/vicapow/jsqrcode

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. However the demo only works if I provide a clean image of a QR code, ie: nothing around, QR-Code takes up 100% of the image and is perfectly aligned. If it is not perfectly aligned or if there is stuff around the QR Code it doesn't work, which makes it almost useless. What I am looking for is a library that will take a random image and extract the QR Code even if there is some parallax and gey and stuff around the QR Code.