# decode QR code from data URI

Tags: javascript, qr-code, data-uri

I try to decode a qr-code from a data uri:

```
var dataUri = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdh9gD2AIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAA9gD2AAAC...';
decodeQrCode(dataUri, cb);
```

I already tried [qrcode-decoder-js](https://github.com/colkito/qrcode-decoder-js) ([example with mocha test](https://jsbin.com/tebobosedi/1/edit?html,js,console,output))

```
function decodeQrCode(dataUri, cb) {
  qrcode.callback = cb;
  qrcode.decode(dataUri);
}
// error decoding QR Code
```

and [qcode-decoder](https://github.com/cirocosta/qcode-decoder) ([example with mocha test](https://jsbin.com/nuvunonawi/1/edit?html,js,console,output))

```
function decodeQrCode(dataUri, cb) {
  var qr = new QCodeDecoder();
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', dataUri);
  qr.decodeFromImage(img, cb);
}
// Error decoding QR Code from Image
```

but it seems to me that both do not support data URIs inherently.

How can I decode a QR code from a data URI?

Comment: Did you base64-decode the dataUri first?

Comment: No, I did not base64-decode dataUri.

Comment: It's not a problem with the dataURI, but with your image. Both libraries do accept dataURI. Also, as a general rule, you should wait for the load events of every of your `<img>` tag before processing it.

Comment: May you please fix one of my examples on JS Bin? I tried to wait for the image to load, but it did not work either.

Comment: [here is one jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sidabucere/1/edit?html,js,console,output) with an other qr code as gif dataURI. You also have a problem in mocha script, where the callback is executed twice, thus producing an error. I don't know mocha so look at the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is that your QR code is not in the good orientation.

Here is the result after rotating it by 90deg :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var img = document.querySelector('img');
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // rotate by 90 deg
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
  ctx.translate(-img.width, -img.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  // decode
  QCodeDecoder().decodeFromImage(canvas.toDataURL(), function(err, res){
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(res||err))
    });
  
}
```

```css
*{vertical-align : top}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cirocosta/qcode-decoder/master/build/qcode-decoder.min.js"></script>
<img id="qr-code" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"
alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How did you hit on the idea to rotate the image?

Comment: I tried your solution with another QR code and it didn't work. My QR codes are created with [qr-encode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-encode). Your solution works if I create the QR code with `qr("content of qr-code", {type: 6, size: 6, level: 'Q'})`, but it does not if I use `qr("content of qr-code", {type: 11, size: 6, level: 'Q'})`.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the library you do use doesn't support so much compression. You may want to search for an other lib which does support qr-code up to version 40 or send an issue to https://github.com/cirocosta/qcode-decoder/issues . Note that it is bad practice to drastically edit questions after having received answers, if the edit do invalidate the answers. This is the case here. You should rollback your edit and open a new question instead.