# Scanning QR codes using only javascript

Tags: javascript, barcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript QR Code Reader - can it be done? Or, Remote Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566972/javascript-qr-code-reader-can-it-be-done-or-remote-service)

Is there any way to scan the bar/qr codes using only javascript.

Comment: JS can't scan barcodes, hardware needed. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you intent to get the QR codes - do you already have them as png, jpg etc or do you need to access the camera?

Comment: wrong! javascript can scan barcodes. thats what the html5 media capture api can be used for.

Comment: I will using one html page where in user will provide the image and press the button to scan... then the function within the javasript will get executed to scan the image and will return the results... this is my requirement... and i don't want to use any canvas objects.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky  could you please put some more info on this... it would be very helpful..thanks.

Comment: @Sirko  i will be using jpg,png files mostly.

Comment: @user1720500, http://webcamtoy.com/app/ there is an example of how the webcam api can be used in javascript. i have tested it myself and i've waited for this api to come into major browsers for ages.

Comment: i should also mention that webcamtoy uses a fallback to flash in case the html5 media capture api is not implemented in the used browser.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky thanks for the info..but this is a cam functionality.. it won't scan the barcode/qr-code images.

Comment: sure. but that was the main thing everyone denied. because this is possible it is no problem implementing an qrcode reader in javascript. sadly i dont know about a pure javascript qrcode read library but you should consider looking at the answer given by nikolaus gradwohl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a javascript port of ZXing which allows you to parse QR Codes in images
or the canvas object.

To use it for scanning barcodes in images generated from a webcam you either need a 
small flashbased module or a browser that already supports the html5 media capture api

https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode

Comment: @NikolausGradwohi  thanks a lot this suits my exact requirement.