# Read qrcode from a web page with camera.

Tags: javascript, camera, qr-code

Im looking for a solution to read a QRCode on a webpage.

Lets say I've generated with PHP and some library (zxing or something else) a QRCode and its printed on a piece of paper, ok?

What i would like to do now, is to read it back with tablet/smartphone throught a web-page.
I browse to that page, it asks me to aim the QRCode with the camera, and then the scanned content is sent back to the page that decodes it.

There's something out there to handle this without the need to use an Android/iOS app?
It could be another type of 2D barcode aswell, not exclusively a QRCode.

TY

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@altack/quar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have once worked with Lazarsoft's `jsqrcode`

It worked fine in the browser, and I know he made a demo to test on a phone with camera.

Here is his repository: https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode

For camera support: use the CamCanvas API: http://www.taboca.com/p/camcanvas/

Comment: Thanks edi, ill give a look at your links.

Comment: I'm trying the jsqrcode test.html, i can see the web cam preview but it's not capturing the qr code, any idea?

Comment: Yes, @Sam, you were likely not making sure to append your 'canvas' object to the webpage. Do that and then use the `canvas.getContext('2d') in order to, every animation frame, draw the image for jsQR to process. You also need to make sure the video height and width are non-zero.

Answer (score 6):

You can read QR Codes using [instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan).

Copy instascan.min.js from the releases page and load with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="instascan.min.js"></script>
```

Sample code to read QR Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>QR Code Reader using Instascan</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="instascan.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="preview"></video>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
      scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
        console.log(content);
      });
      Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
        if (cameras.length > 0) {
          scanner.start(cameras[0]);
        } else {
          console.error('No cameras found.');
        }
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting error in console: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.`. What's the problem?

Comment: ok, turned out, the javascript file in the official release (1.0.0) has bug. This link is preferable `https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js`

Comment: its turning on my MOBILE front camera i want to open back camera is that any option?

Comment: @MAmirShahzad I have the same issue. I believe it's because the docs say that iOS is not supported and I was using iPhone/Safari. If I pressed front or back, only the front camera showed.

Answer (score 1):

Instascan (https://github.com/schmich/instascan) has recently been published and solve many of the drawbacks of Lazarsoft's and the callback solution by @maraca. It uses HTML5 for camera and can be deployed off-line.

Comment: But instascan doesnt work well with android webview, hope this help someone, might considering https://nimiq.github.io/qr-scanner/demo/ or https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR