# HTML5 QRCode Autofocus for small QR codes(2*2) rolled on small 1.5mm diameter lab vials

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, qr-code, react-qr-code

Please Help! I am using HTML5 QRCode react library for QR code and barcode scanning; and I am working on a tight deadline. I have issue scanning QR codes on small vials. Do we have any fix for this.

[image]

Comment: You could test whether it is the bending of the QR code that is the actual problem. If a flat QR code scans perfectly, but one on a vial doesn't, then it stands to reason the bending is the problem. If it is I doubt there's something you can do about that.

Comment: You could try to minimize the amount of information to encode and use a normal bar code. Bar codes can be put on a vial without bending their pattern.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for the quick reply. I tried with an app; and it seems to scan operfectly. But not on the website I am developing to scan the vials.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, flat Qr code is getting read properly. Bending is the problem I think. Any way to fix it.  It s just a string. I dont have the permission to change the standards.

Comment: The problem is the algorithm they use to recognize the QR code. Accounting for bending requires a more complex algorithm, which the app clearly uses and your HTML QRcode doesn't. You could look for another QR code scanner and test it. You do have a choice, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652017/read-qrcode-from-a-web-page-with-camera (link is somewhat old, but Google will help you find newer ones).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably a bit late and not necessarily useful, but Denso Wave have developed a type of QR Code specifically for this issue. Unfortunately it has not yet been given an ISO/IEC specification and only proprietary Denso Wave products can create or read iQR codes.

> iQR Code with rectangular modules, as well as square ones, can be generated. Thanks to this feature, it is possible to overwrite it with a space where a barcode is and to print it on cylindrical products while maintaining the code's readability, which is difficult with codes made up of square modules.

https://www.qrcode.com/en/codes/iqr.html